# sd_notify() from Java

Tags: java, service, systemd

I have a Java service (implemented using [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.io)) which I'm launching from a user instance of [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/).  So far so good.  Now I would like to use systemd's [notification features](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) to make it aware of the service state (available as a [C library function](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) or [shell script](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-notify.html) but eventually both methods talk to a socket referenced by an environment variable).  I can run arbitrary code when the service has finished starting up, but I'm not sure how best to notify systemd from within Java.

Other developers run this service on Windows, so for bonus points it would be really useful if my notification code were discreet and didn't cause any output if not running with systemd.

Comment: Since that notification feature requires native code, you'll need to use JNI and/or JNA.

Answer (score 3):

I found this implementation which does use system hooks, but at least doesn't require JNA/JNI.

https://gist.github.com/yrro/18dc22513f1001d0ec8d

As you say, systemd uses sockets referenced by an environment variable (System.getenv("NOTIFY_SOCKET") in the code), so I'd imagine there may also be a way to use a Java Socket, although I'd imagine a lot of research and/or trial-and-error would be required.

Comment: Good call -- I've yet to find a better solution.  I've removed your link, as it's actually referencing a SO clone's copy of this question.

Comment: This class uses something, forking a child `systemd-notify` process,  that is notoriously unreliable.  [There is a better way.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36992645/340790)

Comment: I've taken the answer from @JdeBP and turned it into something a little more generic: https://gist.github.com/juur/048cc3d0554953b717e9c6867970f30e

Answer (score 0):

There is Java + JNI implementation:

https://github.com/faljse/SDNotify

> The Notify protocol uses datagram unix sockets, which are not accessible via Java; Therefore SDNotify includes a JNA wrapper of the socket API.