# Receiving open sockets from the environment in Java

Tags: java, sockets, systemd

[systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) supports [socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html), which means that sockets will be passed to the daemon process as open file descriptors.  Is there any way to retrieve and use these sockets from Java?

Comment: Yes. As I said in the comments to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27176303/2970947), use JNI and/or JNA.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is what [`System.inheritedChannel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#inheritedChannel()) is for.

On the systemd side, you should be able to make your service file pass the socket as fd 0 (which is what Java expects) by setting `StandardInput=socket`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the pointer I needed.  Not actually tried it, mind, but it seems plausible :).